# custom annotation on class and method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations, customization, aspectj

Is it possible that I put custom annotation on class and then it forceful the developer to put the annotation on method?

suppose I have three custom annotation

1. **@Loggable**
2. **@MySQLLoggable**
3. **@CassandraLoggable**

when I put **@Loggble** annotation on class , it forceful the developer to annotate its all methods either by **@MySQLLoggable** or **@CassandraLoggable**.

update me!

**EDITED**

```
@Loggable // Suppose I put this annotation on class
public class Service {


@MySQLLoggable //eclipse forceful the developer 
              //to put  @MySQLLoggable or @CassandraLoggable on sayHello()
public String sayHello() {
    return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use @interface

```
    public @interface foo {

    String str();

    }



    @foo(str = "str")
    public class myClass{

    }
```

edit

```
    public @interface loggable {

    @loggable1(method) @loggable2(method))
    String foo();

    }
```

Comment: you create custom annotation and just put it to Class. it will not forceful the developer to put another annotation on all the method of class(myClass)

Comment: oh sorry, i misread your question, not sure if i still understood it correctly but:

public @interface loggable {
 
 @loggable1(method) @loggable2(method))
 String foo();
 
}

if you add that to a class you're forced to add them.(added it to the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if you want that IDE make developers use your custom annotations then you better read your IDE specification and possible customization. If you want that later on during execution your app will throw exceptions if methods are not annotated then you have to use reflection. Let's save you use Factory Pattern to create objects. So before create them you can check whether all methods are annotated and if not all then throw an exception. Again I believe you have to use reflection.. this is only one way!

Comment: As I noticed you  tagged it as Spring MVC ) Funny I actually described how this web framework deals when instantiating controllers.

Comment: I have done a similar task when working on auth mechanism. So if you have two roles and want that users could use all methods ,but one which can be called only by admin then you annotate controller and methods. After you use reflection to see whether method belongs to a needed role or not.

Comment: Actually , if user not provide @MySQLLoggable/@CassandraLoggable annotation on methods of annotated class, the program should not compile.

Comment: please share any example if you have? :)

Comment: You can't do it! As I said early you better read how to customize your IDE! Because even if I made it work let's say in Eclipse, nobody restrict another developer to open my class in Netbeans and overpass my restrictions. Again at the low level IDEs just run a compiler so I can just download another compiler and use it. I believe what you are trying to do is completely worthless. Again one chance to archive it is to force all developers to stick with ONE IDE and config this IDE to do that you want. But you might not find an IDE that allows to customize itself in this way!